# react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler X/Y coordinates

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I've setup an [expo snack here](https://snack.expo.io/@smartcris/xy-coordinates), where you can drag an image and see the X/Y coordinates.
I don't understand why if I drag the image on the top left corner, the coordinates are negative numbers.
You could argue that the position is relative to the starting point. But as you can se in the Cardeditor.js file the cardItems state X and Y are both set to 1.
In my app (not in the example) the user is able to navigate to another screen where the cards is in landscape mode, so I have to reposition the image in the correct spot, for this I need to be sure that the top left corner is always x:0 and y:0.
This issue probably has to do with absolute/relative positioning, but I can't find any source of information on the net.

Answer (score 0):

try to main container position:'relative' and other components position: 'absolute'

Comment: Can you please look at my code and change it accordingly ? thank you!